# Self-Referencing Table SQL Select last element from included elements

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have tables:

```
    create table Branches(
    Id int primary key identity,
    IdSection int not null,
    IdMasterBranch int null,
    [Name] varchar(100) not null,
    [Description] varchar(300) null
    )
    
    create table Threads(
    Id int primary key identity,
    IdBranch int not null,
    IdUserAuthor int not null,
    [Name] varchar(100) not null,
    IsPinned bit not null,
    IsOpen bit not null,
    HasPoll bit not null
    )
    
    create table Posts(
    Id int primary key identity,
    IdThread int not null,
    IdUserAuthor int not null,
    Body varchar(4000) not null,
    IsEdited bit not null,
    [Index] int not null,
    Created datetime2 not null,
    Updated datetime2 null
    )
```

Branches is self referencing table, that contains another branches.
And i wanna write sql request to select all master branches (IdMasterBranch IS NULL) with last thread and last post.
Something like this:

```
select * from Branches branch 
left join BranchModerators moderator on branch.Id = moderator.IdBranch 
left join Threads thread on branch.Id = thread.IdBranch 
left join (select * from (
select *,
       ROW_NUMBER() over (
                     partition by IdThread 
                     order by [Index] desc
               ) as RowNumber
  from Posts
  ) groups
  where groups.RowNumber = 1) lastPost on thread.Id = lastPost.IdThread
```

But i wanna take last thread and post with included inner branches too.

What is the best solution for it?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: You've done a great job posting the relevant tables DDL, now all we need is some sample data as DML and desired results.